# Password protect all sites (folders) under a folder

Tags: .htaccess, password, passwd

I have a server where I have a few tester sites in a folder.
Hence all of those tester sites are in `mysites` folder.

What I am hoping is that no one accessing my site is able to go to

- `www.example.com/mysite/`
- or `www.example.com/mysite/site1`
- or `www.example.com/mysite/site2`

I want everything under `www.example.com/mysite/` to be password protected. Is it possible?

Maybe through `.htaccess`?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use .htaccess to do that.

There is an answer on how to use it here :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5229656/password-protecting-a-directory-and-all-of-its-subfolders-using-htaccess

Answer (score 0):

A [`.htaccess`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/htaccess.html) is recursive by default:

> .htaccess files (or "distributed configuration files") provide a way
>   to make configuration changes on a per-directory basis. A file,
>   containing one or more configuration directives, is placed in a
>   particular document directory, and the directives apply to that
>   directory, **and all subdirectories thereof**.

Just place your `.htaccess` to `mysite` directory and use the [authentication example](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/htaccess.html#auth).